# pip Python 3.3 windows 7

Tags: python, pip

Good evening.

I'm trying to install pip on python 3.3 (win7) and everything looks good but console shows the following message:

```
C:\Python33>pip
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1519, in _find_and_load_unlocked
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__path__'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python33\Scripts\pip-script.py", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pip==1.5.6', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
  File "C:\Python33\pip.py", line 17466, in main
    bootstrap(tmpdir=tmpdir)
  File "C:\Python33\pip.py", line 17436, in bootstrap
    cert.write(pkgutil.get_data("pip._vendor.requests", "cacert.pem"))
  File "C:\Python33\lib\pkgutil.py", line 627, in get_data
    loader = get_loader(package)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\pkgutil.py", line 482, in get_loader
    return find_loader(fullname)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\pkgutil.py", line 499, in find_loader
    pkg = importlib.import_module(pkg_name)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 90, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1584, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1565, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1522, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ImportError: No module named 'pip._vendor'; pip is not a package
```

the path is fixed then I don't know what's wrong

```
C:\Windows\System32>path
PATH=C:\Python33\Scripts;C:\Python33\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\
System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)
\Intel\OpenCL SDK\3.0\bin\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\3.0\bin\x6
4;C:\Users\kamome\AppData\Local\Temp
```

Do you know what's happening?
Thanks

Comment: What does `where pip` show you?

Comment: Baah. Just install Python 3.4 and have `pip` preinstalled with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pip is installed in the Script subfolder, `Python33\Scripts\Pip.exe`, and not in the main python folder.